# keyup event for input inside of a dynamic HTML loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do the multiplication of two HTML inputs as they are typed. This code works for one of the tables.

HTML:

```html
{%extends "dashboard.html"%}
{%block content_A%}

            {% for o in org.office %}
                <div class="col-md-18">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="header">

                                <h4 class="title">Weekly Report for {{org.organization_name}} {{org.organization_ID}}</h4>
                                <p>Office: {{o.owner_name}} {{o.office_ID}}</p>
                                <p>Week ending: {{we.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')}}</p>
                                <p>Invoice submitted: {{today.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')}}</p>
                          <table>


                                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                                            <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                                      {% if t[1] == o.office_ID%}
                                                                        <h3>Backpacks: {{t[0]}}</h3>
                                      <h5>Per Piece Profit: {{t[2]}}</h5>
                                      <h4>Total Backpack Profit: {{t[4]}}</h4>
                                      {% else %}
                                      <h3>Backpacks: 0</h3>
                                      {% endif %}
                                      <hr>
                                                                    </div>
                                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                                      <h3>Hotlines:</h3>
                                      <div class="form-group row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                                          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="hln" maxlength="4">
                                          <input class="hidden" type="text" name="or" value="{{t[3]}}">
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                     <h5>Per Piece Profit: {{t[3]}}</h5>
                                      <h4>Total Hotline Profit:</h4>
                                      <input type="text" name="hlnt" readonly />
                                   </div>
                                                               </div>
                              </div>
                              </table>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Here is the Jquery that does the

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "[name='hln']", function() {

  var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
  var or = $('input[name="or"]').val();
  $('input[name="hlnt"]').val(value * or);
});
```

This works on a single table, however the html is created dynamicly in a Jinja for loop.
 When there is more than one table the value is entered into all of them.

Comment: _“however the html is created dynamicly in a Jinja for loop.”_ - then remove any IDs from it first of all (or have them include some dynamic counter suffix) - IDs must be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: You need to be more specific with the selection of your elements. One way to do that, would be to go up to the container element first, and then use that as context for the following element selections.

Comment: I have removed the id,'s. I was only using them for a different failed attempt at learning Jquery. Still same result. I feel like the problem is somehow I need to specify what table the result goes in. currently they all get the answer.

Comment: 04FS could you please explain a little? I am very ignorant to anything Jquery. I will update my html with full

Comment: Go read up on https://api.jquery.com/parents/, and the `context` parameter, https://api.jquery.com/jquery/ From your `hln` button, on which the event occurs, you go upwards to the `<div class="col-xs-6">` element first - and then you use that element as context, when selecting the other two elements `or` and `hlnt`, so that they are only selected within that common ancestor element, and not within the whole document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the working example below it will work based upon the [child](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_descendants.asp), [parent](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_ancestors.asp) and [sibling](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_siblings.asp) relationship  or DOM Elements and will set the value according to which element the value has been changed

I have copied the code twice so that you can see changing value from one will not set values in all total `fields`

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "[name='hln']", function() {

  var value = parseFloat($(this).val());

  // it will select the sibling element which mean the [name='or'] element1
  var or = parseFloat($(this).siblings("input[name='or']").val()); 

  // find the parent of input with class 'parent-class' and then find its child with name hlnt and set the value to it
  $(this).parents(".parent-class").find('input[name="hlnt"]').val(value * or);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6 parent-class"> <!--add class here-->
  <h3>Hotlines:</h3>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="hln" id="hot" maxlength="4">
      <input class="hidden" type="text" id="ovr" name="or" value="3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <h5>Per Piece Profit: 3</h5>
  <h4>Total Hotline Profit:</h4>
  <input type="text" name="hlnt" id="output-value" readonly />
</div>
   
 <!--copied same content as above to see how this work as saperately withot affeting others->
<div class="col-xs-6 parent-class"> <!--add class here-->
  <h3>Hotlines:</h3>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="hln" id="hot" maxlength="4">
      <input class="hidden" type="text" id="ovr" name="or" value="4">
    </div>
  </div>
  <h5>Per Piece Profit: 4</h5>
  <h4>Total Hotline Profit:</h4>
  <input type="text" name="hlnt" id="output-value" readonly />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a general selector like `$('input[name="hlnt"]')` this will get all the `hlnt` named inputs in the page. Instead find a common parent for the `hln` and `hlnt` inputs and search from that parent:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "[name='hln']", function() {
  $this = $(this);
  //get closest parent
  //https://api.jquery.com/closest/
  let parent = $this.closest('.col-xs-6');

  var value = parseFloat($this.val());
  var or = parent.find('input[name="or"]').val();

  //use find() to find the child element
  parent.find('input[name="hlnt"]').val(value * or);
});
```